# Is this just a numerical accident or what?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

In a complementary proof for a matrix determinant of $a_{i,j}=\binom{n-1+i}j$, [raised by BillyJoe](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423216/determinant-of-matrix-with-stirling-numbers-as-elements/423375#423375), I showed the more general evaluation
$$\det\left(\binom{i+p}{j+k-1}\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq m}
=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\binom{p+m-j}m}{\binom{m+k}m}. \tag1$$
From another [MO post of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423513/an-identity-for-schur-polynomials?noredirect=1#comment1088435_423513), I gathered very useful pointers by Richard Stanley and Gjergji Zaimi which lead me to dig up [a paper of A. N. Kirrilov](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01104977.pdf). In this paper, on page 121, I have found the formula
$$\dim(\omega_k^m)=\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\binom{p+m-j}m}{\binom{m+j}m} \tag2$$
where $\omega_k^m$ is an irreducible representation of the Lie group $SU(p+1)$ which is the $m^{th}$-symmetric power of the fundamental representation $\omega_k$. Here, $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_p$ are the fundamental irreducible representations of the Lie group $SU(p+1)$.

The coincidence of (1) and (2) was striking to me. So, I am now prompted to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a direct connection between the determinant on the LHS of (1) and the dimension $\dim(\omega_k^m)$ on the LHS of (2)? Such as, an interpretation of one in terms of the other, conceptually not just as a numerical accident.

**Postscript.** The fact that (1) is directly expressible in the language of plane partitions (PP) is quite evident. However, I still would like to see such fact (reference) for the LHS of (2) running with PP.

Comment: Aren't these both just counting plane partitions in a box? (C.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition#Plane_partitions_in_a_box)

Comment: Can you direct me to where $\omega_k^m$ has been interpreted as a count on plane partitions?

Comment: This is well-known. For example, if we rotate 180 degrees and add $i$ to the $i$th row, we get SSYT of rectangular shape.

Comment: (Meanwhile, probably you are aware of this, but the determinant you've written should be a LGV-type determinant for plane partitions interpreted as non-intersecting lattice paths.)

Comment: Okay, regarding the postscript, as I said this is well-known but if you want a specific reference, check out Theorem 2.2 of Kuperberg's "Self-complementary plane partitions by Proctor's minuscule method" (https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411239).

Comment: @SamHopkins: That is nice and useful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you meant "complementary" rather than "complimentary" and I edited the question accordingly. Both are standard words, but their meanings differ from each other.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks!