Inverse relationship between Stirling numbers of the first and second kind via generating functions
In combinatorics, a well-known result is that the matrix formed by the Stirling numbers of the second kind $\left(S(n,k)\right)_{n,k\geq 0}$ and the matrix of the signed Stirling numbers of the first kind $\left((-1)^{n-k}c(n,k)\right)_{n,k\geq 0}$ are inverses of each other. This result has many proofs, including bijective and generating function approaches.

My question concerns the interpretation of this relationship in terms of bivariate generating functions. Specifically, we know the generating functions:
$$
S(u,z) := \sum_{n,k\geq 0} S(n,k) u^k \frac{z^n}{n!} = \exp(u(e^z-1)),
$$
and
$$
s(u,z) := \sum_{n,k\geq 0} (-1)^{n-k} c(n,k) u^k \frac{z^n}{n!} = (1+z)^u.
$$
Is it possible to directly derive the inverse relationship between $\left(S(n,k)\right)_{n,k\geq 0}$ and $\left((-1)^{n-k}c(n,k)\right)_{n,k\geq 0}$ from the relationship between $S(u,z)$ and $s(u,z)$? For example, could this be achieved via a differential equation or some other analytical method?

Maybe look up the keyword "exponential Riordan array". Also somewhat related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418266

The inverse relationship is obvious if you use the generating functions $$ \sum_k (-1)^{n-k} s(n,k)x^k = x(x+1)\cdots (x+n-1)$$ and $$\sum_{n\geq k}S(n,k)x^n = \frac{x^k}{(1-x)(1-2x)\cdots (1-kx)}. $$

Also for what it's worth, $s(n,k)$ is normally the notation for the signed Stirling numbers of the 1st kind, whereas $c(n,k)=|s(n,k)|$ is used for their absolute values. For instance, this is what Wikipedia uses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number

Be aware that there are two different matrices and sets of polynomials associated with each set of Stirling polynomials and different index offsets as well. See, e.g., https://oeis.org/A008277 and https://oeis.org/A048993.

If you write $s(u,z)$ as $\exp(u(\log (1+z))$ then the inverse relation becomes clear—$\log(1+z)$ is the compositional inverse of $e^z-1$. More generally, if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are compositional inverses then we have similar inverse matrices formed from the coefficients of $\exp(u f(z))$ and $\exp(u g(z))$.

@IraGessel Your brief answer is what I want. Grateful!

@IraGessel, isn't that what I demonstrated a week earlier in my answer explicitly rather than just claim? To be precise, $f(x) = \sqrt{z}$ and $g(z) = z^2$ are compositional inverses, choosing an appropriate branch cut along the negative real axis, but there are no lower triangular inverse matrices associated with them. One could also choose Laurent series that are comp inverses and the same problem would occur. In addition, the Appell Sheffer polynomial sequences, which also have associated pairs of inverse coefficient matrices, have such cuz of a multiplicative inversion relationship.

Rather I show almost explicitly. One has to make the last leap/connection between umbral composition and the multiplication of lower triangular coefficient matrices, which applies to all Sheffer polynomial sequences--binomial, Appell, and generic.

@TomCopeland Yes, you did demonstrate this explicitly in your answer.

@IraGessel, I know that you've published at least one paper on the umbral calculus, and your knowledge of combinatorics is much deeper than mine in most areas. Can you point me to any papers where you've applied the hybrid umbral Sheffer operator calculus or similar to a blend of geometry or topology and combinatorics? (I'm always looking for such.) If so, please send me a note at tccopeland at gmail.

@TomCopeland I have only one paper on umbral calculus. My approach could be described as applications of linear functionals on polynomials to identities for generating functions. I have not made any connections to geometry or topology, and I haven't done anything with Sheffer sequences.

Well, all general composition partition polynomials are Appell Sheffer sequences in a distinguished indeterminate--that of the linear term--as well as one core compositional inversion set of partition polynomials, so it would be a feat to avoid Sheffer sequences in commutative algebra.

In umbral notation and maneuvers, it's quite simple. With an obvious change of notation, let the Stirling polynomials of the first kind (a binomial Sheffer sequence of polynomials in the hybrid umbral-finite operator calculus) be denoted by
$(ST1.(x))^n = ST1_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n ST1_{n,k}x^k$
and similarly for the binomial Sheffer polynomials $ST2_n(x).$
The e.g.f.s are
$$e^{x\ln(t+1)} = e^{ST1.(x)t}$$
and
$$e^{x(e^t-1)} = e^{ST2.(x)t}.$$
Then umbral composition gives
$$e^{ST2.(ST1.(x))t} = e^{ST1.(x)(e^t-1)} = e^{x\ln[1+(e^t-1)]} = e^{xt},$$
and, of course,
$$e^{ST1.(ST2.(x))t} = e^{ST2.(x)(\ln(1+t))} = e^{x[e^{\ln(1+t)}-1]} = e^{xt},$$
implying that the two polynomial sequences form an umbral compositional inverse pair, i.e.,
$$ST2_n(ST1.(x))= x^n = ST1_n(ST2.(x))$$
In terms of the pair of lower triangular matrices of coefficients of the two sequences, this implies the pair of matrices is an inverse pair.
The diff op reps of the two binomial Sheffer sequences are
$$ST2_n(:xD:) = (xD)^n$$
and
$$ST1_n(xD) = :xD:^n = x^nD^n,$$
where $:xD:^k = x^kD^k$ by definition with $D = \partial_x$. Then we have the diff op equivalent of the umbrally compositional inverse relation:
$$ST2_n(:xD:) = ST2_n(ST1.(xD)) = (xD)^n$$
and
$$ST1_n(xD) = ST1_n(ST2.(:xD:)) = :xD:^n.$$
The e.g.f.s follow from the conjugation $Ad_{e^{-x}}$ as
$$e^{ST2.(x)t} = e^{-x} e^{ST2(:xD:)t}e^x = e^{-x} e^{txD}e^x =e^{-x}\sum_{n\geq 0} e^{tn}\frac{x^n}{n!} = e^{x(e^t-1)}$$
and from $Ad_{x^{-y}}$ as
$$e^{ST1.(y)t} = x^{-y} e^{ST1.(xD)t}x^y = x^{-y} e^{t:xD:}x^y =\sum_{n\geq 0} \binom{y}{n}t^n = (1+t)^y = e^{y\ln(1+t)}.$$
In addition, the lowering ops defined for any Sheffer polynomial sequence $P_n(x)$ by
$$L_P P_n(x) = n \; P_{n-1}(x)$$
are given by the inverse functions in the arguments of the e.g.f.s as
$$L_{ST1} = e^{D}-1$$
and
$$L_{ST2} = \ln(1+D).$$
If we go one step further and define the finite difference operator
$$\delta_x = e^{\partial_x}-1 = L_{ST1},$$
then
$$\partial_x = \ln(1 + \delta_x),$$
and we have an entre into the finite difference calculus with reps of the (Heaviside fractional) differ-integral calculus and the Appell Sheffer Bernoull polynomials and function (essentially the Hurwitz zeta function) along with their umbral inverses with their connections to the Bernoulli-Todd-Hirzebruch operator and class, exact Euler-MacLaurin series, volumes of lattice polytopes, the BCH theorem, and more via the ops
$$ \frac{\partial_x}{\delta_x} = \frac{\partial_x}{e^{\partial_x}-1} = 
\frac{\ln(1+\delta_x)}{\delta_x}$$
and their multiplicative inverse ops
$$ \frac{\delta_x}{\partial_x} = \frac{e^{\partial_x}-1}{\partial_x} = \frac{\delta_x}{\ln(1+\delta_x)}.$$

You can go the Riordan array route, but that's a baby only a pure algebraist or computer programmer can love. I prefer Riordan's and others' umbral and diff op approach.

For the inverse relation using operational calculus and o.g.f.s along with other common notation, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172955/ordinary-generating-function-for-bell-numbers/172969#172969 where $ST2_n(x) = \phi_n(x)$ are called the Bell polynomials (also called the Touchard / exponential / Steffensen and probably should be called the Scherk polynomials as well) and $ST1_n(x) = (x)_n = x!/(x-n)!$ are called the falling factorials.
